# Algorithm to find duplicates in multiple linked lists

Tags: algorithm, optimization, linked-list

What is the fastest method of finding duplicates across multiple (large) linked lists.
I will attempt to illustrate the problem with arrays instead just to make it a bit more readable. (I used numbers from 0-9 for simplicity instead of pointers).

```
list1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
list2[] = {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1};
list3[] = {4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3};
list4[] = {8,2,5};
list5[] = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5};
```

If I now ask: 'does the number 8 exist in list1-5?' I could sort the lists, remove duplicates, repeat this for all lists and merge them into a "superlist" and see if the number of (new) duplicates equal the number of lists that I search through. Assuming that I got the correct number of duplicates I can assume that what I searched for (8) exists in all of the lists.
If I instead searched for 1 I will only get four duplicates—ergo not found in all of the lists.

Is there a faster/smarter/better way to achieve the above without sorting and/or changing the lists in any way?

P.S.: This question is asked mostly out of pure curiosity and nothing else! :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just traverse all lists and search for 8 instead of that sorting/removing duplicates story?

Comment: @Klark I think he knows the cost for any one query is O(n), using that trivial algorithm, and wants to amortize the cost over multiple queries.  @Waxhead I think you're best off re-representing the data by placing it in a tree, hash table, or counting bloom filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array `hash` and set all the location values to 0

```
define hash[MAX_SYMBOLS] = {0};
define new_list[LENGTH]
defile list[LENGTH] and populate
```

Now for each element in your `list`, use this number as an index  in `hash` and increment that location of `hash` . Each presence of that number would increment the value at that `hash` location once. So a duplicate value `i` would have `hash[i] > 1`

```
for i=0 to (n - 1)
  do
    increment hash[list[i]]
endfor
```

If you want to remove the duplicates and create a new list then scan the `hash` array and for each presence of `i` ie. if `hash[i] > 0` load them into a new list in the order in which they appeared in the original list.

```
define j = 0
for i=0 to (n - 1)
  do
    if hash[list[i]] is not 0
      then
        new_list[j] := i
        increment j
    endif
endfor
```

Note that when using with negative numbers you will not be able to use the values directly to index. To use negative numbers, first we can find the largest magnitude of the negative numbers and use that magnitude to add to all the numbers when we use them to index the `hash` array.

```
find the highest magnitude of negative value into min_neg

for i=0 to (n - 1)
  do
    increment hash[list[i + min_neg]]
endfor
```

Or in implementation you can allocate contiguous memory and then define a pointer at the middle of the allocated memory block, so that you could move in both front and back directions so that you can use negative index with it. You need to make sure that you have enough memory to use in front and back of the pointer.

```
int *hash = malloc (sizeof (int) * SYMBOLS)
int *hash_ptr = hash + (int)(SYMBOLS/2)
```

now you can do `hash_ptr[-6]` or some `hash_ptr[i]` with `-SYMBOLS/2 < i < SUMBOLS/2 + 1`

Answer (score 6):

Just put each number into a hash table and store the number of occurrences for that item in the table. When you find another, just increment the counter. O(n) algorithm (n items across all the lists).

If you want to store the lists that each occurs in, then you need a set representation to be stored under each item as well. YOu can use any set representation -- bit vector, list, array etc. This will tell you the lists that that item is a member of. This does not change it from O(n), just increases the work by a constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague, so the answer depends on what you want.

A hash table is the correct answer for asking general questions about duplicates, because it allows you to go through each list just once to build a table that will answer most questions; however, some questions will not require one.

Possible cases that seem to answer your question:

Do you just need to know if a certain value is present in each list? - Check through the first list until the value is found.  If not, you're done: it is not.  Repeat for each successive list.  If all lists are searched and the value found, it is duplicated in each list.  In this algorithm, it is not necessary to look at each value in each list, or even each list, so this would be the quickest.

Do you need to know whether any duplicates exist at all?
- If any value in a hash table keyed by number has a count greater than 0, there are duplicates...  If that is all you need to know, you can quit right there.

Do you need the number of duplicates
    in each table, separately?
-  Multiply each value by the number of lists and add the number of the list in process.  Store that as the hash key and count duplicates.  When all lists are processed, you have a table that can answer all kinds of questions. To check duplicates for a specific value, multiply it by the list count and examine sequential hash keys.  If there is one for each list, the number is present in each list.  If all the counts are greater than 1 over that range, the number is duplicated in each list.

Etc.